# Efficiently Loop through thousands of array items and make api call for each item that isn't in local storage

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise

I have an array of objects. Each object represents a day and has 2 properties - date and items. Items is an array of objects where each object has information about some website. I want to enhance each website object by using a 3rd party api to fetch some data using the website's url.

In order to do this more efficiently, I've decide to cache data from the api using local storage. So for each website object in one of my items arrays, I look to see if the api information for that specific website has been cached and use that instead of making an api call. If the data isn't cached I will call the api and then add the data to local storage for next time.

I'm struggling to get my code working for this and looking for an elegant solution. I've also encountered an issue with my current code where the 3rd party api gives me a 429 error for making too many request in a short period of time so ideally my solution will have some way of throttling my requests.

What is the right way to handle this scenario? Are there any 3rd party libraries that might make this easier?

```
// I want to pass in array of objects like so:
//
// [
//  { date: '12/31/2019', items: [{...}, {...}, {...}, etc] },
//  { date: '01/01/2020', items: [{...}, {...}, {...}, etc] },
//  { date: '01/02/2020', items: [{...}, {...}, {...}, etc] },
// ]
//
// into the enhanceData function and get back the same array of objects,
// but with each object's individual items enhanced with the 3d party data

const enhancedData = await enhanceData(sortedData);
```

Here is my current code for handling this:

```
// fetch 3rd party data for the given hostname
const fetchSiteData = (hostname) => {
  axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'apiurl.com',
    params: someParams,
    headers: someHeaders,
  })
    .then((response) => {
      // handle response stuff and returns the data
      return { ...someData }
    })
    .catch((e) => console.error('api error', e));
};


// see if the api data for each item has been stored locally, fetch from api if not
const enrichItems = (items) => {
  console.log('ENRICHITEMS items', items);
  const enrichedItems = items.map((item) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const { hostname } = new URL(item.url);
    chrome.storage.local.get(hostname, (cached) => {
      if (cached[hostname]) {
        console.log('found cached value', { ...cached[hostname] });
        resolve({ ...item, alexa: { ...cached[hostname] } });
      } else {
        console.log('no cached value');
        fetchSiteData(hostname)
          .then((siteData) => {
            console.log('siteData', siteData);
            chrome.storage.local.set({ [hostname]: siteData }, () => {
              if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
              } else {
                console.log('item stored successfully', { ...siteData });
                resolve({ ...item, alexa: { ...siteData } });
              }
            });
          })
          .catch((e) => reject(e));
      }
    });
  }));
  console.log('enrichedItems', enrichedItems);
  return Promise.all(enrichedItems);
};


// should return once each items array has been enhanced
export const categorizeData = (data) => Promise.all(data.map(async (day) => {
  const enrichedItems = await enrichItems(day.items);
  return {
    ...day,
    item: [...enrichedItems],
  };
}));
```